# How to predict using only weights obtained from glmnet in R?

Tags: r, predict, glmnet

One can make predictions using `predict(fit,newx)` method. But how to predict if I don't have the fit object itself but only the weights of the predictors as vector file and new observations for predictors as a matrix file? The predictors and the outcome both are continuous variables.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Is this a linear regression or logistic (or something else)? For linear predictions you just multiply the observations by the weights and sum them. For logistic you do the same multiplication and sum but have to transform the result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Definition_of_the_logistic_function

Comment: thanks @Pdubbs thats what I assumed. But wanted to confirm.

Comment: @Pdubbs it actually doesn't matter what kind of model, you can do the same procedure with anything in glmnet, since they are all generalized linear models.

Comment: You can multiply and sum, but to get anything useful to a human out of logistic coefficients you need to transform them with 1/(1+e^(-score)) . Likewise different transforms for things other than OLS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use matrix multiplication, which is what glmnet does.  In the predict function, it is: `as.matrix(cbind2(1, x) %*% coefs)`

Example:

```
library(glmnet)

x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y=rnorm(100)
fit1=glmnet(x,y)
coefs <- coef(fit1,s=0.01) # extract coefficients at a single value of lambda

manaul_pred <- as.matrix(cbind2(1, x) %*% coefs)
pred <- predict(fit1,newx=x,s=0.01)

manual_pred - pred # there is a negligible difference due to numeric precision
```

Comment: Will the prediction is valid, if, of all the predictors used in fitting only some are available ?

Comment: If the missing predictors only have small coefficients, yes.  If they have large coefficients, it may not be valid.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to assess that while performing the prediction? Can I just compare the means of absolute values of coefficients between predictors present and absent in dataset?